# How to move SQL Server 2008 to the cloud?

Tags: sql-server-2008, hosting, cloud, azure-sql-database

I have a large (~**40gb**) SQL Server 2008 database that I would like to move to the cloud.
The database uses a lot of SQL Server 2008 specific (and non-specific) features (SQLCLR, xml, indexes, partitions, etc). Thus, my preference would be to use the exact database, but in the cloud.

What are my options? The new SQL Azure only allows small databases, and a subset of TSQL. I want to whole thing. I would still like to connect to it using Management Studio.

Comment: Thanks for your edits marc_s.

Comment: Seems quite large - and hosting that with Azure or any other hoster will probably cost you a bundle. Have you done any serious calculations whether it wouldn't be cheaper to host it yourself and put it on a e.g. clustered server with a hosting provider?

Comment: If I do that, how do I expose a connection end point to the internet?

Comment: As of June 2010, 40g won't be an issue, as a new 50gb SQL Azure size will be available. See the SQL Azure Team Blog announcement at http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlazure/archive/2010/03/19/9981936.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want "the whole thing" and want to be able to connect to your SQL-Azure store with SSMS, you'll have to wait until SQL Server 2008 R2 (a.k.a. SQL Server 2010) is out - sometime in 2010.

The SQL Server 2008 R2 November CTP has just had such an [announcement](http://blogs.msdn.com/ssds/archive/2009/11/10/9920168.aspx) - the SSMS for that version will be supporting SQL Azure.